# rspec stub giving wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am upgrading from rails 3.2.19 to rails 4.1.5. I am using rspec-rails 2.14.0.rc1.

With rails 4.1.5 all my tests are passing, except for a handful that use stub. The ones that are failing are of the form:

```
ENV.stub(:[]).with("ADWORDS_RUN").and_return("Yes")
Rails.stub(env: ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
Kernel.stub(:rand).and_return(2)
```

Each is returning `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)`.  All were passing in rails 3.2.19. I have tried going back to rspec-rails 2.8.1, but same error. Also rails 4.0, but the error persists.  The last error (stubbing :rand) does not occur when I run the whole test suite but does occur when I run the individual test file for that test. Here is an example test

```
it "should have google tracking code in production" do
  Rails.stub(env: ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
  get :home
  response.body.should =~ /Google Analytics Tracking code/
end
```

and here is the output from the test:

```
 Failure/Error: Rails.stub(env: ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)
 # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:107:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Line 107 is the Rails.stub line.

Please let me know how to rectify this problem?

Comment: If you have `gem 'minitest', require: 'minitest/autorun'` in your Gemfile, try changing it to `gem 'minitest'`

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: FYI, I ran your code in RSpec 3.0 and it passed. Is there some reason you're using an old version of RSpec?  Have you run those three lines by themselves? In any event, if you want more help, I'd suggest you post the specific line that raised the error and ideally the stacktrace?

Comment: In response to Santosh, I do not specify minitest in my gemfile, but I do have ```require 'minitest/autorun``` in my spec_helper.rb.  In response to Brad Werth, each of the lines gives the error, they are used in different tests. In response to Peter Alfin, I started off using rspec 3, but ran into trouble with spork, so went back to rspec 2.  How do you get the stacktrace when the line is not causing an exception, i.e. it is just a failing test.

Comment: As far as I know, `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)` is not output as a result of failing test (i.e. failing expectation).  It's resulting from the execution of some statement somewhere.  Can you share your exact output?

Comment: In response to Peter Alfvin's request I have added in the relevant test output to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not manage to find the cause of this problem, but I did find a workaround. It was to change all the `stub` statements to the newer rspec `allow` syntax. So for example

```
 Rails.stub(env: ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
```

becomes

```
allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
```

I did this using rspec-rails 2.14.0.rc1.  This fixed the problem.

Thank you for the comments, they either clarified my question or pointed me  in the right direction.