# Upgraded to Rails 4, and now getting "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I recently upgraded my app from Rails 3 to Rails 4, and I'm trying to run the specification tests. Code that I presume used to work just fine (before my time here) suddenly throws an error.

The error:

```
1) Admin::ReviewsController while logged in #index should get index
     Failure/Error: stub_search("product")
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)
     # ./spec/support/searchkick_stub.rb:5:in `stub_search'
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/reviews_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the searchkick_stub.rb:

```
module SearchkickStub
  def stub_search(model)
    klass = model.to_s.camelize.constantize
    klass.any_instance.stub(:reindex) { true }
    klass.stub(:search) do |term, options|
      options ||= {}
      @search_term ||= term
      @search_params ||= options.dup

      response = {
    'hits' => {
          'total' => 0,
          'hits' => [],
    }
      }
      result_opts = {
    # per Searchkick::Query.new
    page: [options[:page].to_i, 1].max,
    per_page: (options[:limit] || options[:per_page] || 100000).to_i,
    padding: [options[:padding].to_i, 0].max,
    load: options[:load].nil? ? true : options[:load],
    # per Searchkick::Query.execute
    includes: options[:include] || options[:includes],
    json: !options[:json].nil?,
      }
      Searchkick::Results.new(klass, response, result_opts)
    end

    # Code that reindexes Products will reindex their Inventories too.
    stub_search(:inventory) if model == :product
  end
end
```

The signature of stub_search is clearly for a single argument, not two or more like the error claims.

And here is where we use stub_search in reviews_controller_spec.rb

```
describe ReviewsController do
  include SearchkickStub

  before do
    stub_search(:product)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give the whole of SearchkickStub? The trace says that the issue is on line 5 of searchkick_stub.rb. Shot in the dark, but it might be a different call to stub_search that's generating the error?

Comment: Also, not related to your immediate question, but even Rails 4 is somewhat old now. Rails 4.2 itself is going to be end-of-life'd soon. If your goal is to get your app up to date, you might want to consider skipping a step and going right to Rails 5 or even 6.

Comment: Edited. Hm. Line five is calling "klass.stub(:search)". Thanks, maybe that'll help.

Comment: And believe me, I know. But we're just trying to upgrade from Wheezy to Jessie, and ruby and rails along with that. It's as far as we're able to upgrade things just now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082894/rspec-stub-giving-wrong-number-of-arguments-error Looking at this now.

Comment: Did you happen to upgrade the Ruby version too?

Comment: Yes. To 2.1.5 from 1.9.3 or so.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Per https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/941, the issue was the line: `require 'minitest/autorun'` in spec_helper.rb. This line was added to remove the followig warnings:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
```

But it turns out that all you need is `gem "minitest"` in the Gemfile (even though it was already installed, as a dependency for something else, and appeared in Gemfile.lock).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes more from the ruby upgrade. There may have been changes to the interpreter around how block arguments were handled. The search method is stubbed to take 2 arguments in your code: `term` and `options`. But it's only invoked with one argument: `"product"`.

`options` is set to a default value on the first line in that block with `options ||= {}` so not passing options may not have been a problem with 1.9.3, but with stricter argument checks it breaks in 2.1.5.

---

A simple fix is to set a default argument in the block arguments, eg.

`klass.stub(:search) do |term, options|`

to

`klass.stub(:search) do |term, options={}|`

You can also safely remove the `options ||= {}` line after doing this.

Comment: I _might not_ be 100% correct on the reasoning, but using a default argument in the block declaration should fix your bug.

Comment: Getting the same error, but thank you for responding :)